# Downloading file with browser works but not with wget or curl

Tags: curl, wget, cloudflare, download

I want to download a certain mp3 file with the link 
https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=nXyzYpK93EDxQlXaw%2FQ66x0PVPyTnb9VHoplZFoWlLqyK7gKf%2BDVpsfnkibHs94vjrqryBfJce0ZJiTSESmm2g%3D%3D

If I access this link with a browser (Chrome) I get redirected to a mp3 file and it downloads automatically. But if I use wget or curl it just downloads a text/html file that it was redirected to. 
Has anyone encountered this issue? I dont know if it is because of missing headers, Cloudflare on the server I want to download it from or anything.

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: the link seems to open a webpage which offers the download...